# Finding the odds of the total of 5 numbers being between $x$ and $y$, where the odds of the values in each number being on a bell-curve?

Tags: probability

The only way I can see to solve this is to brute force it (aka just work out every possibility by hand). However, even in a program the 'formula' would be quite elaborate.

Here is my problem: I'm trying to come up with a genetic system for a computer game. Characters have 5 stats that can range from 0 to 12 individually. Regardless of the values, the total of the five has to be between 30 and 42 for any given character.

The values are determined for offspring by averaging each stat for the two parents, then for each rolling two random numbers between 0 and 12. The one closer to the average for that stat is chosen, unless they are of equal distance in each the winner is decided by a coin flip (technically a random number between 0 and 1). This means the odds of each value should be on a bell-curve peaking at the average.

As if this isn't complicated enough, as said the total in the end needs to be between 30 and 42. In theory, there's a total of over 300,000 possible combinations. Only a small fraction of those though would be within the allowed range. This isn't too hard to calculate, but such a formula relies on all possibilities having an equal chance of coming up. As I said, the odds of each value are on a bell curve, and for any character they would be biased towards a total of 30 and 42 due to the parents always having values in this range.

The best way to solve this would be to just have the program do all the rolls again if the total isn't in the allowed range, but considering the sheer number of possibilities this may require thousands of rolls for each character. There is a better method, but it involves taking the total with each roll, and once its in the allowed range a 0 is put into the remaining stats without rolling. I don't really like that.

Can I just have my program re-do the rolls until it gets an allowed set, or do I need to do the crude method and just stop rolling when an allowed total is reached? If I did the first method, on average how many re-rolls would be needed per character generated?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables#Independent_random_variables

Comment: So, you're saying that if the bellcurve for any given number should be the same as their total? So the odds of the total being 0 should be the same as any given number coming out to be 0?